# Jquery change function don’t work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have same id, name two html select. If I change first html select then it’s work properly but If I change second html select then it’s not work. Please can someone point out what I may be doing wrong here? Many thanks. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>the title</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#name").change(function(){
          $.post(
             "data.php",
             $("#testform").serialize(),
                 function(data) {
                $('#stage1').html(data);
             }
          );
          var str = $("#testform").serialize();
          $("#stage2").text(str);
      });
   });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="stage1" style="background-color:blue; color: white">
          STAGE - 1
   </div>

<form id="testform">
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td><p>Fruit:</p></td>
 <td>
     <select id="name" name="name[]">
         <option>Apple</option>
         <option>Mango</option>
         <option>Orange</option>
         <option>Banana</option>
     </select>
 </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td><p>Fruit:</p></td>
 <td>
     <select id="name" name="name[]">
         <option>Apple</option>
         <option>Mango</option>
         <option>Orange</option>
         <option>Banana</option>
     </select>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Php code:

```
<?php
$fruit=$_REQUEST["name"];
$n = count($fruit);


for($i=0;$i<$n; $i++)
{
    echo $fruit[$i]."<br/>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `id`'s should be unique - using `ID` selector will always/only get you the first element it comes across with the ID

You can use

```
$('select[name="name[]"]')
```

to get both your selects

Answer (score 1):

That is because the

```
$("#name")  // id selector
```

Will only select the first element with the id and ignore the second one..

The ID on your page should be unique.. Try replacing it with a class instead and it should work fine..

`$(".name") ;` // Change your id="name" to class="name"  instead

Answer (score 1):

The `id` attribute is unique and can only be used to select one element. Once the first one is found, no more are expected to exist.

If you want to group multiple elements together, use the `class` attribute, which can be targeted using `.classname`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ids should be unique. The reason, because javascript finds only the first element with "id" it encounters.

   ```
   $('#name')
   ```

   Above selector code will select the first element with the id as "name".
2. Class is used for this purpose. Javascript will create an array of the elements with "class" it encounters.

   ```
   $('.name')
   ```

   Above selector code will select all the elements with class as "name". This can be the possible solution for your question. That is, if you change any of the two select elements in both case the 'change' event will be fired.